# How to generalize this JS to work with all buttons of a particular type?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I'm not sure if my post title is specific enough for the question I'm asking. I couldn't think of any other way to phrase it.

I am building a rudimentary CSM and I'd like to have the following "Edit" button at the side of every entry. When the button is clicked, a drop-down menu is displayed. Each button and corresponding *ul* tag would have unique IDs based on the post it's attached to.

How can I generalize the following JS code to work with every button, regardless of ID, instead of being dependent on getting element by ID?

Here's the button markup.

```
<button id="someId" aria-expanded="false">Edit</button>
<ul class="list-edit text-black" id="someOtherId" style="display: none; margin-top: 10px;">
    <a href="#">
        <li class="list-items-edit">Edit</li>
    </a>
    <a href="#" class="popup-with-zoom-anim">
        <li class="list-items-edit">Unpublish</li>
    </a>
    <a href="#" class="popup-with-zoom-anim">
        <li class="list-items-edit">Delete</li>
    </a>
</ul>
```

Here is the JS.

```
const toggle = document.getElementById('someId')
const content = document.getElementById('someOtherId')

const show = () => {
  toggle.setAttribute('aria-expanded', true)
  content.style.display = "block"
}

const hide = () => {
  toggle.setAttribute('aria-expanded', false)
  content.style.display = "none"
}

toggle.addEventListener('click', event => {
  event.stopPropagation()
  JSON.parse(toggle.getAttribute('aria-expanded')) ? hide() : show()
})

const handleClosure = event => !content.contains(event.target) && hide()

window.addEventListener('click', handleClosure)
window.addEventListener('focusin', handleClosure)
```

Comment: are you using bootstrap for this? if so, there is a way to do this without adding any javascript of your own.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done with multiple ways, One way to surround each dropdown with a container `div` and give it all same class, and then use `querySelectorAll` to select all the dropdowns, and loop throw, and on each dropdown, use `querySelector` to get the `button` and `ul`.

```js
const dropdowns = document.querySelectorAll('.dropdown');

dropdowns.forEach(dropdown => {
const toggle = dropdown.querySelector('button')
const content = dropdown.querySelector('ul')

const show = () => {
  toggle.setAttribute('aria-expanded', true)
  content.style.display = "block"
}

const hide = () => {
  toggle.setAttribute('aria-expanded', false)
  content.style.display = "none"
}

toggle.addEventListener('click', event => {
  event.stopPropagation()
  JSON.parse(toggle.getAttribute('aria-expanded')) ? hide() : show()
})

const handleClosure = event => !content.contains(event.target) && hide()

window.addEventListener('click', handleClosure)
window.addEventListener('focusin', handleClosure)
})
```

```html
<div class="dropdown">
<button aria-expanded="false">Edit</button>
<ul class="list-edit text-black" style="display: none; margin-top: 10px;">
    <a href="#">
        <li class="list-items-edit">Edit</li>
    </a>
    <a href="#" class="popup-with-zoom-anim">
        <li class="list-items-edit">Unpublish</li>
    </a>
    <a href="#" class="popup-with-zoom-anim">
        <li class="list-items-edit">Delete</li>
    </a>
</ul>
</div>

<div class="dropdown">
<button aria-expanded="false">Add</button>
<ul class="list-edit text-black" style="display: none; margin-top: 10px;">
    <a href="#">
        <li class="list-items-edit">Add</li>
    </a>
    <a href="#" class="popup-with-zoom-anim">
        <li class="list-items-edit">Unpublish</li>
    </a>
    <a href="#" class="popup-with-zoom-anim">
        <li class="list-items-edit">Delete</li>
    </a>
</ul>
</div>
```